# BigQuery partition with local time

Tags: google-bigquery

Wondering how to get local time for day partition BigQuery table ?
For far, I only this query :

```
bq mk --time_partitioning_type=DAY exports.partition
```

Is there any way to specify the timezone, so we get local time partition table ?

Answer (score 1):

Specifying a timezone is not supported. A workaround is to load to a partition directly, e.g. [yourtable$20170601](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/partitioned-tables#addressing_table_partitions), so it aligns with your local timezone.

Comment: how to generate 2010601 before insertion ?

Comment: what do you mean?

Comment: @Tensor, do you mean generate the partition? You don't need to generate the partition before insertion. The partition will be created automatically when you insert/load data into it.